# Finding cycles in data using a periodogram and Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: r, data-visualization, interpretation, seasonality, fourier-transform

Problem: Detecting cyclical patterns in daily data using periodogram and FFT.

The issue is how to code in R the periodogram to detect monthly, quarterly, semi-annual, annual..etc cyclical patterns in the data. In other words I need to detect the existence of cyclical patterns for low frequencies (i.e., `1 year => 2*pi/365`, `6 months => 4*pi/365`, etc.).

Reproducible Example:

```
library(weatherData)
w2009 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2009)
w2010 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2010)
w2011 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2011)
w2012 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2012)
w2013 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2013)
w2014 = getWeatherForYear("sfo", 2014)
w = rbind(w2009, w2010); w=rbind(w, w2011); w=rbind(w, w2012) 
w = rbind(w, w2013); w=rbind(w, w2014)

# Next we analyze the periodograms
# This is IMAGE 1
TSA::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF)
# Next: I dont really know to use this information
GeneCycle::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF)
# Next THIS IS IMAGE 2
stats::spectrum(w$Max_TemperatureF)
```

How do you interpret these images?

[image: TSA Periodogram]

[image: Spectrum Periodogram]

Comment: The part of your question concerning 'how do you interpret these images' is on-topic here, but the part asking 'how do you code...' is off-topic. Be aware that you may not get answers to that part.

Comment: Of course, but I will be glad to at least have a partial answer than no answer ! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The periodogram (a scaled squared FFT) shows strong  concentrations of variance in frequencies close to zero --exactly which cannot be ascertained from your plots.

The periodogram is an inconsistent estimator of the spectrum of a stationary time series, hence the very erratic behaviour you see in your second plot. In order to gain a further insight in your series, you should either smooth the periodogram (look at argument `spans=` and `taper=` of `spec.pgram()`) or resort to a parametric
estimate of the spectrum (look at `spectrum(...,method="ar")` and choose the autoregressive order using AIC for instance).